# Symfony Undefined index

Tags: symfony, interface, undefined-index

I am creating an application that fetches and search for product name from different sources (DB, XML, JSON, ...)(for this code Im testing only with the DB), my idea was to create an interface for that.
I created the interface ProductRepositoryInterface and the class DoctrineProductRepository then I declared them both as services. 
In my controller, I call the search function with the product name as param. 
Here is my interface ProductRepositoryInterface :

```
namespace Tyre\TyreBundle\Repository;
interface ProductRepositoryInterface
{
function search(string $needle);
}
```

My interface DoctrineProductRepository:

```
namespace Tyre\TyreBundle\Repository;
class DoctrineProductRepository implements ProductRepositoryInterface
{
    public function __constructor(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function search(string $needle)
    {
        $repository = $this->em->getRepository('TyreTyreBundle:Products');
        $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->where("u.name LIKE '%".$needle."%' or u.manufacturer LIKE '%".$needle."%'")
        ->getQuery();
        return $query->getArrayResult();
        }
}
```

My Service.yml

```
services:
      Tyre\TyreBundle\Repository\DoctrineProductRepository:
         class: Tyre\TyreBundle\Repository\DoctrineProductRepository

      Tyre\TyreBundle\Repository\ProductRepositoryInterface:
         class: Tyre\TyreBundle\Repository\ProductRepositoryInterface
```

and finally my controller :

namespace Tyre\TyreBundle\Controller;

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Tyre\TyreBundle\Repository\DoctrineProductRepository;
use Tyre\TyreBundle\Repository\ProductRepositoryInterface;


class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return $this->render('TyreTyreBundle:Default:search.html.twig');
    }
    public function searchAction(Request $request) {

        $repositoryMap = [
            'db' => DoctrineProductRepository::class,
        ];
        $serviceName = $repositoryMap[$request->get('db')]; /***This is Line 56 ***/
        /** @var ProductRepositoryInterface */
        $repository = $this->get($serviceName);
        $results = $repository->search($request->get('search_for'));
        return $this->render('TyreTyreBundle:Default:detail.html.twig', array('results' => $results));

    }

    public function detailAction()
    {
        //forward the user to the search page when he tries to access directly to the detail page
        return $this->render('TyreTyreBundle:Default:search.html.twig');
    }
}
```

But I get an error : 
[image: click to view]

**EDIT**

When I try http://localhost:8000/search?db=db , I get other error (I var_dumped $repositoryMap) :
[click to view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gwgU.png)

Am I missing anything?

Comment: The error is self-explanatory: `$request->get('db')` is not returning anything or is returning an index key which does not exist in the `$repositoryMap` array.

Comment: hmmm, how can I fix that? a var_dump for $repositoryMap gives array(1) { ["db"]=> string(52) "Tyre\TyreBundle\Repository\DoctrineProductRepository" }

Comment: Again, look at your code.  $request->get('db') is undefined.  Nothing in your route is setting db.  Maybe update your question with your search route.

Comment: Fix your routing.

Comment: your code could work if you access with the correct query string value as example `http://localhost/index?db=db`

Comment: I got error when I used http://localhost:8000/search?db=db, see my update

Comment: try `$request->request->get('db')`

Comment: I tried, got the same error Undefined index

Answer (score 1):

The reason for your 'ContextErrorException' is :

```
$request->get('search_for')
```

is empty because you are passing nothing in the url for that key. Pass '**search_for**' also in addition with '**db**' like:

http://localhost:8000/search?db=db&search_for=myvalue